# Does Aweber have a send email API but broadcast does not solve the problem?

Tags: laravel, aweber

I was about to start developing my companies website which is currently in research phase. I was researching with the Aweber API (https://api.aweber.com/) but did not find the API for using a send mail function.

I came across Create Broadcast API here

```
https://api.aweber.com/#tag/Broadcasts/paths/~1accounts~1{accountId}~1lists~1{listId}~1broadcasts/post
```

but this requires a list to be used I want to send email to individual contact in the list separately. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Approved a suggest by mistake How to undo it?

Answer (score 0):

AWeber's API can only send broadcast messages to a list, or a previously created segment of subscribers. You cannot send messages out to a single person solely using the API.

You could use the web UI to create a segment of "email address is ...", then get the segment and send the message to it using the API, but that requires an extra step.